# React component lifecycles still run after redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

In my component I want to check if a user is logged and if not, then redirect to the login page. Currently I do the check and redirect in componentWillMount.

```
  public componentWillMount() {
    if(this.props.master === null) {
      this.props.history.push('./login');
    }
  }
```

However even though the redirect does occur both render() and componentDidMount() are still run, which crashes my code because in there I assume master is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a mechanism like this one:

[When user is not logged in redirect to login. Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476186/when-user-is-not-logged-in-redirect-to-login-reactjs)

To redirect the user to the login page on the router, instead of the restricted component.

And please be careful with `componentWillMount` since it will be deprecated in future versions.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: Ahh, so you wrap your component inside another component, which decides to display it. Good solution, I will try it and if it works will mark this answer as accepted. It's a shame the react-router examples don't have any accompanying explanation.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply but this method worked well and the implementation is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> If `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false, then `componentWillUpdate()`, `render()`, and `componentDidUpdate()` will not be invoked

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  if (this.props.master == null) return false
}
```

Answer originally from: [Stop rendering of a component after componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364753/stop-rendering-of-a-component-after-componentdidmount)

Comment: Doesn't prevent initial render.