# How to call setState with componentDidMount without causing extra calls to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with `componentDidMount`: everytime that i use `setState` in `componentDidMount` it calls `render` several times in `child components`, and I don't know why... look:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const firstName = localStorage.getItem('nameLoggedUser');
  const lastName = localStorage.getItem('lastNameLoggedUser');
  const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`.toLowerCase();

  const loggedUserIs = localStorage.getItem("user-role");
  const emailLoggedUser = localStorage.getItem('emailLoggedUser');

  if (loggedUserIs === 'full') {
    axios.get(`/api/menuDomain`)
      .then(res => this.setState({
        domain: res.data
      }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

It gives this:
[image]

But, if I use `ComponentDidUpdate`, it gives:
[image]

That is correct, but the AJAX call is not happening...

I want to make the AJAX call and not have it render several times... But I don't know how... Could someone help me? Please???

And I am using `react-router` too:

```js
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/" render={() =>
            <Overview
              {...myProps}
            />
            } 
            />

          <Route path="/list" render={() =>
            <Graphic
              {...myProps}
            />
          } />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop rendering of a component after componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364753/stop-rendering-of-a-component-after-componentdidmount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never wrap your routes within a stateful component. Instead, the routes should be a stateless function that just returns the same JSX route elements. For the example above, you should use a `HOC` that wraps your protected routes and is only concerned with authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53197429/7376526

Second, you shouldn't be storing the logged in user in plain text within local storage. Instead, it and possibly the password should be stored within a [JWT token](https://jwt.io/) (or within some sort of hashed plus salted token) or perhaps within a secured cookie and then decoded and compared against server-side. How you're currently setting it to localStorage is incredibly insecure and anyone can simply set a user's first and last name and their "user-role" and gain access to their account.

Third, each `container` should handle and fetch relevant data and pass it to a relevant `component` for display. For performance, you should compartmentalize your retrieved data to relevant data for that particular component. Since you have multiple routes, fetching everything at once is wasteful. For example, fetch `Overview` data inside of a `FetchOverview` container's `componentDidMount`, then pass it down to a `DisplayOverview` child component for display. Read this for more information on `containers` and `components`: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: Hello friend, how are?? I have loved your answer!! And i going to make, but i have a question... Can i to make a `componentFetching` using `ComponentWillReceiveProps` ? That to make a request when receive a new props ???

Comment: Either use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState)` and do some sort of `prop` or `state` comparison to update the data (`componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated) OR create a `handleOnClick` parent `method` that is passed down to a child's `onClick` event handler -- this should simply trigger an update in the parent's `state` (for example, making another `AJAX` call), where the `state` gets updated and passed back down to the child. Ideally, the parent remains stateful and the child remains statless; however, the child can call a parent method to update the parent's state.

Comment: In addition, if you're worried about "There's no data to display yet, how can I show a spinner?", then you'll want to use conditional rendering: https://codesandbox.io/s/zm3mqw2m4 (see containers/SimpleForm.js for an example of conditional rendering -- I am using and comparing against `isLoading` in the `render` method to show a spinner or show a form).